# Application got slower after migrating to dotnet core 2.1 from dotnet core 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have migrated my ASP.NET Core 1 application to ASP.NET Core 2.1 and it got about two times slower. I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer nuget package Version="2.1.0-rc1-final". I would like to know what can cause such issues.

Comment: application got slower is not a real measure. What went slower? Db calls?

Comment: Yes entity framework queries got lot slower

Comment: You know you're using a release candidate of EF? The version 2.1 should be released around 30th of may, have a look at this for more info on your version : https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/2.1.0-Early-Access-Downloads

Comment: How about a code-braking change in the framework that generates a lot of exceptions?

Comment: EF core, is currently trying to get a RC for version 5.0 
3.1 is the current release. 
But 3.1 is actually a lot more annoying than 2.1 when you have large queries, with high complexity.

2.1 should however be faster? So that is very odd.

Would you show code? Input? Output? Diagnostics of how you calculate performance? etc.